# Ansible loops in lineinfile

Tags: vagrant, ansible

Commenting out multiple lines should work with a standard loop [1] like this:

```
 - name: "Allow /srv folder accessed by default. Just comment out the lines to allow."
lineinfile: dest=/etc/apache2/apache2.conf regexp={{ item.regexp }} line={{ item.line }} state=present
with_items:
  - { regexp: '#<Directory /srv/>', line: '<Directory /srv/>' }
```

But I got an error:

```
      failed: [192.168.101.101] => (item={'regexp': '#<Directory /srv/>', 'line': '<Directory /srv/>'}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"line": "<Directory /srv/>", "regexp": "#<Directory /srv/>"}} 
msg: this module requires key=value arguments (['dest=/etc/apache2/apache2.conf', 'regexp=#<Directory', '/srv/>', 'line=<Directory', '/srv/>', 'state=present'])

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

So how to get this working with multiple lines/items?

[1] http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you, tedder42! You we're more than right.

To be idempotent, the lineinfile task needs to match both the commented and uncommented state of the line so we start it: ^#? 
So the fully functioning play set out to be:

```
 - name: "Allow /srv folder accessed by default. Comment out the lines to allow. "
     lineinfile: 
       dest=/etc/apache2/apache2.conf 
       regexp="{{ item.regexp }}" 
       line="{{ item.line }}" 
       state=present
     with_items:
       - { regexp: '^#?<Directory /srv/>', line: '<Directory /srv/>' }
       - { regexp: '^#?\tOptions Indexes FollowSymLinks', line: '\tOptions Indexes FollowSymLinks' }
       - { regexp: '^#?\tAllowOverride None', line: '\tAllowOverride None' }
       - { regexp: '^#?\tRequire all granted', line: '\tRequire all granted' }
       - { regexp: '^#?</Directory>', line: '</Directory>'}
```

This is actually not a good idea. Definitely better is use the copy with backup=yes.

Answer (score 1):

You were *really* close to having it working. Simply add quotes around the regexp and line.

```
 lineinfile: dest=/etc/apache2/apache2.conf regexp="{{ item.regexp }}" line="{{ item.line }}" state=present
```

I wasn't entirely sure, but the error message implied there were problems with seeing the `regexp` and `line` args, so I tried a few things.

As a reminder, `lineinfile` is somewhat of an antipattern. When you find yourself using it, that's a sign you should consider switching to `copy` or `template`.